# .Net 5 Web API make jquery POST fails

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

That's really sucking my brain out, I can't pass data to my POST method in my controller no matter of what try, the issue is passing through a jQuery ajax call, this is my JS code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/token",
            data: {'': 'Hello Web API'},
            success: success,
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
        function success(data) {
            console.log("new token response: ") 
            console.log(data) 
        }
```

and this is my server code:

```
// POST api/Token
    [HttpPost("")]
    public string Post([FromBody]string accessToken)
    {
        //var jData = Json.d;
        var token = accessToken;
        return token;
    }
```

I've documented about with this links: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), [Using jQuery to POST [FromBody] parameters to Web API](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/) but nothing works.

Why is so complicated, please any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) - section **FromBody**, you should consider to change your request like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/token",
            data: JSON.stringify('Hello Web API'),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: success
        });
        function success(data) {
            console.log("new token response: ") 
            console.log(data) 
        }
```